# Migration does not alter my table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I just enabled migrations in my project and added a few fields to `UserProfile`:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set;}
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastAccess { get; set; }
}
```

I `Add-migration AddFieldsForUserProfile` and it created:

```
    ...
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "Email", c => c.String());
        AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "Description", c => c.String());
        AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "CreatedOn", c => c.DateTime());
        AddColumn("dbo.UserProfile", "LastAccess", c => c.DateTime());
    }
    ...
```

`Update-database -verbose` yielded this output:

```
Target database is: 'Hifi.Models.HifiContext' (DataSource: (localdb)\v11.0, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
Applying code-based migrations: [201303311011083_AddFieldsForUserProfile].
Applying code-based migration: 201303311011083_AddFieldsForUserProfile.
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] ADD [Email] [nvarchar](max)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] ADD [Description] [nvarchar](max)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] ADD [CreatedOn] [datetime]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] ADD [LastAccess] [datetime]
[Inserting migration history record]
Running Seed method.
```

Apparently all went well, but after recieving an error that the coloumn CreatedOn does not exist, I looked into the database with the Server Explorer and indeed, all 4 coloumns are missing in my `UserProfile` table. What did I do wrong?

## Edit

I found my error. Somehow I had two different `mdf` files `aspnet-Hifi-20130330054424.mdf` and `Hifi.Models.HifiContext.mdf` which had the same file size and I assumed both were necessary. My Server Explorer was using the `aspnetxx.mdf` and the database changes were made to `HifiContext.mdf`. Shame on me.

On a related note I had trouble correctly displaying a list of all registered users. It was always empty altough I could login flawlessly. Somehow for login `aspnetxx.mdf` was queried but my `MemberListController` queried `HifiContext.mdf`. After changing my connection string I had initially no registered users, new ones were added to `HifiContext.mdf` and the list worked properly. How did this happen?

Comment: are you sure you're looking at the right Db? it seems so though. Did you get any errors? Any special permissions etc. My advice is to create a new connection (e.g. config and `<connectionStrings><add name="HifiContext" connectionString="Data Source=MACHINE\INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=HiFi;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>`) - and backup your old just in case. i.e. recreate Db from scratch.

Comment: I have no other and have seen no errors, a user I create in my seed() method exists and others I registered before from my application. `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Hifi-20130330054424;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Hifi-20130330054424.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: try recreating if you just turned migrations on - no other idea

Comment: @NSGaga well, you were right and I was dumb ;) Edited my question..

Comment: if that solved it - would you like me to put this (comments) as an answer so you could close this question (that's a good way, also good for your reputation), let me know.

Comment: Sure, go ahead. Can you explain my other issue?

Comment: I tried to explain a bit in the answer, cheers and glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you're looking at the right Db?
it seems so though. Did you get any errors? Any special permissions etc.

My advice is to create a new connection - e.g. config and

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="HifiContext" connectionString="Data Source=MACHINE\INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=HiFi;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>`
```

...and backup your old just in case. i.e. recreate Db from scratch

If nothing works - try recreating if you just turned migrations on - no other ideas.

As for why the out-of-sync happened - hard to say for sure - but I'm guessing you had 'two connection strings' as well (or at some level).

> Make sure that you connection string is 'named' the same as your
>   `dbcontext` - or put connection at your at DbContext directly

. It is sometimes a problem, as it's not apparent what the EF/CF 'makes' as its default.

Answer (score 0):

call this method in your startup code to have the database recreated with the new fields:

```
public void CheckForDBChanes()
        {

            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>());
        }
```