# Migration not working as I wish... Asp.net EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was studying this tutorial asp.net  Movie Tutorial and I have 2 simple files in my model.

```
 public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }


}

public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }


}
```

And the other one is the Account Model that Visual Studio gives me :

```
 public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }


}
```

The problem is.... If  I add a propety

```
 public int aaa { get; set; }
```

to the UserProfile class, I get no changes in the migration....This happens because the migration only updates class that are inside the MovieDBContext.... So I must add something like:

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> User{get;set} 

}
```

The problem is that in another project I am trying to update the AccountModel and tried this solution but it didnt work.... Does anyone know another solution?

Comment: you said in the comment below that your login functionality breaks when you put them all in one DbContext class. What about the login breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I think what you're experience is a 'connection' problem**. (please check this out for a walkthrough I made earlier - and the connections link)
[Migration does not alter my table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730662/migration-does-not-alter-my-table/15734839#15734839) (for connection issue)
[Code first create tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747162/code-first-create-tables/15747585#15747585)

**Put it into a single DbContext** - you don't really need two (at least I think so). You just need to 'adjust' the connections when you do.

> Specifically your `UserContext` has a connection specified
>   (`DefaultConnection`).   The other one (Movie...) does not - that
>   means the other connection will be named `MovieDbContext` - and it
>   tries to find it in your config file - if it doesn't succeed - it uses
>   your default 'provider' to find the Db - and it creates a new Db
>   there. While your UserContext probably already has a defined connection in the .config - and that one works.

Just move all to 'UserContext' - or adjust connections. see attached

**Note:**

Having multiple DbContext-s is what's called **multi-tenant migrations** - it's not supported as of yet (for EF5) - and is coming for EF6 [Multiple Contexts per Database in EF6](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations).

It simply cannot have 'two migration tables' in the same database - as each migration/context requires its own.

For a 'hack' you could force the `Add-Migration` to run - by doing something like `Add-Migration -ConfigurationTypeName Test.Migrations.MovieConfiguration InitialMovie` - and separately for the other one - but that won't work in a single project (it'd complain for migrations pending or something) - and if you move to two different - you'll hit 'one migration table' wall once you run the Update.

**The other solution would be to turn off migrations** (for one) but I haven't tried that - or run two context connecting to two databases - which you don't really want if you want to 'communicate' in between sort of. Either way - this is just for 'academic purposes' purely - it's not for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all of your tables in a single `DbContext` class.

Everything will then work correctly.

Comment: I cant do that.... If I change the place of public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; } ... the login functionality of my website stops working

Comment: I don't agree with this. It is better to separate everything according to its bounds, or what Julie Lehmann calls "Bounded Context". It provides also other performance benefits, etc.

Comment: Yeah, i agree with Husein, but is it possible to have "Bounded Context" with Model-First approach? Or is it only available for Code-First?

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework will only migrate one DbContext. Period. There's no way around this, currently. That means very plainly and simply that everything that EF will need to work with *must* be in this single context.

However, that doesn't preclude you from using other contexts elsewhere for different purposes. So in your `MovieDBContext` go ahead and add your `UserProfile` entity set:

```
public DbSet<UserProfile> User { get; set; }
```

Then, in your other contexts, you just need to 1) make sure they interact with the same database and 2) that they don't have an initialization strategy, e.g.:

```
public class AccountsContext : DbContext
{
    public AccountsContext()
        : base("name=ConnectionStringNameHere")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(null);
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> User { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

That will make EF treat this context as a mapping to an existing database, so it won't try to create database tables, migrations, etc. All that will be done via your primary context (`MovieDbContext` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `enable Migration` like this :

```
Enable Migration -ContextTypeName UsersContext
```

or you can define `public DbSet<UserProfile> User { get; set; }` in your `MovieDBContext` like this :

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> User{get;set} 

}
```

and use this way :

```
Enable Migration -ContextTypeName MovieDBContext
```