# DbContext constructor with connString causes problems with EF Migrations and EF Powertools

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext

I would like to pass a connection string to the constructor of DbContext.  The way to do this has been answered here: [Pass connection string to code-first DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805094/pass-connection-string-to-code-first-dbcontext)

(code if you don't like to click)

```
public MyContext(string connString)
    : base(connString)
{

}
```

However, when I attempt to enable migrations I receive the error: "The target context '...' is not constructible.  Add a default constructor or provide an implementation of IDbContextFactory."

Also, when I attempt to use EF PowerTools to generate an Entity Data Model is receive the error: "A constructible type deriving from DbContext could not be found in the selected file."

Is this a common problem?  I have a fix, but it feels like a hack.  Any one else have to deal with this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add also an empty constructor, e.g...

```
public MyContext()
{
}
```

Thing is once you define a parametrized ctor your default one gets hidden

e.g. see [Why does the default parameterless constructor go away when you create one with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792207/why-does-the-default-parameterless-constructor-go-away-when-you-create-one-with)

That's also one way of 'hiding' default construction from the outside users.

---

Usually you don't even expose that 'other' ctor to the outside - as its 'yours', you just hardcode inside what you need. Or alternatively and better - you use the 'app.config' to specify the connection string. For details (and problems with it) see...

[Migration does not alter my table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730662/migration-does-not-alter-my-table/15734839#15734839)
[Migration not working as I wish... Asp.net EntityFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794413/migration-not-working-as-i-wish-asp-net-entityframework/15795166#15795166)

Comment: Haha, it must have been a long day.  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: np :) usually you don't even expose that 'other' ctor to the outside - as its 'yours' DbContext you just hardcode inside what you need. Or alternatively you use the 'app.config' to specify the connection string.